# Using SSL with command-line Flywaydb ( flyway ) to deploy DB changes

Tags: mysql, sql-server, deployment, flyway, continuous-deployment

I'm working on a proof of concept to deploy using flyway's command-line tool from a centralized server to deploy to multiple database platforms. (MySQL, Postgres, and SQL Server)

I'm able to deploy successfully without SSL, however it is using unencrypted host information such as logins/passwords/ports to the destination Database Server.  My concern is there's a chance the un-encrypted traffic could be seen.

Does anyone have experience with the flyway command line tool using SSL to deploy to:
MySQL
SQL Server

I did not see any information in the documentation unless I missed it.

Thanks for any help and suggestions!

Comment: Since I have not seen any traction, I thought I'd place a comment to perhaps someone may know off hand.  Since flyway uses the jdbc driver SSL is available.  I am thinking just like a developer can add SSL to their connection string, the same could be done for Flyway?  Does that seem possible?

Comment: Hi Normoe - have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

In the flyway examples in flyway.conf it shows how to add additional values to the jdbc url for example

```
# MySQL             : jdbc:mysql://<host>:<port>/<database>?<key1>=<value1>&<key2>=<value2>...
# PostgreSQL        : jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/<database>?<key1>=<value1>&<key2>=<value2>...
# Redshift          : jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/<database>?<key1>=<value1>&<key2>=<value2>...
```

So for Redshift/Postgres for example you can include the ssl=true flag

```
flyway.url=jdbc:postgresql://yourserver:5439/dbname?ssl=true
```

You need to add the public key that the DB server key was signed with to your hosts trust store (for Redshift see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-ssl-support.html for details on that), e.g

```
${JAVA_HOME}/bin/keytool -keystore ${JAVA_HOME}/lib/security/cacerts -import -alias <alias> -file <certificate_filename>
```

I then had to hack the flyway startup script /flyway to include the truststore and password in the JAVA_ARGS (it probably should have these as variables) e.g

```
JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/../dev/urandom -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/pki/java/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit"
```

Answer (score 2):

For MySQL I used the following URL to connect using SSL.

`jdbc:mysql://hostname:3306/wpastudy?useSSL=true`

Note the `useSSL=true` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

For postgresql, the option is ?ssl=true

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34183798)